# Nothing to do in this review but "No action needed"

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, locked-questions

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/33771

In this locked question it is not possible to do anything. Only "No action needed" and "Skip" are enabled, and clicking that will throw "STOP! Look and Listen." box

Comment: You should just Skip such things, it's like falling into a big obvious hole in the road. That said, I agree it's a bug, answers in locked questions should't be used as audits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - But how can answers in locked questions come in *First Posts*? Or it's just because it is Audit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's like falling into a big obvious hole in the road so that you can call the authorities saying there should be an invisible piece plexiglass covering the hole :-)

Comment: @hims056 the answer was posted at 18:00:47 while the question was locked about one hour later. Probably it was the user's first post and received flags and downvotes hence marking it fit as audit.

Comment: seems to be a dupe. ping me if I misunderstood something